# Cant Get Specific Post Attachments in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to retrieve all of the images associated with a post. I am able to return the ID and to print the ID but when I try to add it with the arguments for get_posts() it returns an empty array. If i don't include a post_parent it gives me all of my images that I have in my media library not all of the images for the post I am looping over. Am I not looping at the right level?

Ive tried manually adding the ID and it still returns an empty array.

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
     'post_type'      => 'attachment',
     'posts_per_page' => 1,
     'post_parent'    => get_the_ID()
) );

var_dump($attachments);
```

I am expecting a list of the attachments for the post. I want to grab an image from the attachments and print it to the page. But I keep getting empty arrays. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The Wordpress Codex says:

> Whilst the default WP_Query post_status is 'publish', attachments have
>   a default post_status of 'inherit'. This means no attachments will be
>   returned unless you also explicitly set post_status to 'inherit' or
>   'any'

So you should try to add `'post_status' => 'inherit'` to your arguments array.

Comment: Still bringing up an empty array. Is it possible my loop is set up incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Simplyuse the wordpress core function [get_attached_media()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/) to get the attachments of your post.

> get_attached_media( string $type, int|WP_Post $post )
>
> Retrieves media attached to the passed post.

Simply pass an empty string as $type to bypass the mimetype filter.

Comment: When I use this [ with a get_+the_ID() ] It still returns an empty array. I tried to even hardcode the post ID and still, an empty array.

Comment: thats only possible, if you haven't properly attached the media to specified post.. check your Media Library and read [this support article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-image-and-file-attachments/#attachment-to-a-post) for more information about how to attach a media to a specific post using the media library.